# SSL Handshake issue on Android 7.0

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate, android-7.0-nougat

I have a backend built in Java and Springboot and deployed on railway.
When i tested the endpoints on various Android versions from 14 till 6 and they all worked except on Android 7.0 (Nougat), where i keep getting this error message for every network request i make:

`java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

I haven't tried much of any solution.
I use retrofit and it is for my android app in kotlin.

What do i do to solve it?

Comment: Do you have any custom networking configurations in use defined for example in `network_security_config.xml`?

Comment: May I know if the url is ssl cert already?

Comment: No i don't have any network config file. @MarkusKauppinen

Comment: Yes it is SSL certified, @TicherhazFreePalestine

Answer (score 0):

This exception is saying that phone doesn't trust the SSL Authority. As [@Markus Kauppinen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78218801/ssl-handshake-issue-on-android-7-0#comment137897195_78218801) suggested in comment, you have to setup [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-config).

1. Download your server certificate and save it into `raw` resources directory.
2. Create `network_security_config` file in `xml` resources directory and setup configuration for your server domain. If your app communicates with other servers like Firebase, don't forget to include them too:

[image]

In `network_security_config.xml` just replace **yourdomain.com** with your actual domain.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">yourdomain.com</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/server_cert" />
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

3. Apply config in `AndroidManifest.xml`, put in into `application` tag

```xml
<application
   android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
   ...
>
```

With this solution it should work fine for Android 7+.

Comment: certificates src="@raw/server_cert" does not exist

Comment: @AdrianIK I wrote it in step 1, you have to download your server certificate and put it there.